# .jar doesn't run external program

Tags: java, eclipse

So i have a java project made in eclipse with sphinx voice recognition. If i say a certain word then it runs a .bat file.

```
if (resultText.equals("word")) {

    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    try {
        runtime.exec("C:/c.bat");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In Eclipse it works fine, but after i export the .jar and run it, if i say that specific word, it doesn`t run that .bat. So any ideas why this only runs my .bat file from eclipse and not from command line? Thanks

Comment: Well what diagnostics have you tried? There could be any number of problems here - how sure are you that it's recognizing the word properly? Are you looking at the output to see if there's an exception?

Comment: Are you experiencing any errors?

Comment: i don`t get any error. It recognizes the word, because it also writes the word i'm speaking, but it does not run the .bat

Comment: What about some logging? There is simply no replacement for a few well placed System.out.println()... or logger.log() if you prefer.

Comment: It can be that under Windows 7 Eclipse runs as administrator but command prompt doesn't. So it has no permission to  `C:\c.bat`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this but atleast try this solution once.

Try giving the .bat file path as `C:\\c.bat` and then try again.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding something like:

```
File f = new File("c:/c.bat");
if(f.exists()) {
  // execute the file
  Process process = runtime.exec(f.getAbsolutePath());
  process.waitFor();
  InputStream stdout = process.getInputStream();
  InputStream stderr = process.getErrorStream();
  // check the streams for errors
} else {
  // log error
}
```

*hth*